# On dragover change border of highlighted element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm using inline CkEditor version 4.6 for email creation inside my application.

There are multiple content blocks inside which user can enter content.

The content blocks have a default 2px dashed border applied on them to differentiate among each other.

If an image is dragged over to the content blocks, I need to hightlight that content block with a border so that the user knows which column they are dropping the image into. On leaving the drag the border should be back to what it was i.e. the default. Also when I drop the image inside the target the border should revert back to default.

I'm able to achieve this using the following code below -

```
function changeBorderColor(parentClass) {
$(".cke_editable").parents(parentClass).each(function () {
      $(this).on("dragover", function () {
          $(this).css("border", "2px solid #00ADE6");
      });
      $(this).on("dragleave", function () {
          $(this).css("border", "2px dashed #c0c0c0");
      });
      $(this).on("drop", function () {
          $(this).css("border", "2px dashed #c0c0c0");
      });
  });
}

changeBorderColor(".threeRowLayout");
```

The issue arises when when I send a test email.

In the test email the borders remain applied i.e. the dashed one used in the function above. Also if any links are part of the email content they don't render.

This is not the default behavior of the application. Only on writing the above code the issue arises.

Can someone please provide their thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Well to answer my own question, the issue was with the line of code -

```
$(this).css(--------);
```

Whenever I sent a test email the border was applied by the above line of code. Therefore I never achieved my desired result.

To solve it, I modified the above line to apply a class -

```
$(this).addClass(----)
```

in the case of 'dragover' and -

```
$(this).removeClass(----)
```

in case of 'dragLeave' and 'drop'.

Now whenever I drag an image over the content block the class gets added and on leave or drop the class gets removed, hence not showing up in the test email as well.